# Show price based on value from select menu

Tags: jquery, forms, select, input

Here is my form HTML code.

```
<form>
<select id="country1">
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
<input name="amount1" value="" readonly="readonly" />

<select id="country2">
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
</select>
<input name="amount2" value="" readonly="readonly" />

<select id="country3">
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
</select>
<input name="amount3" value="" readonly="readonly" />

</form>
```

Now on the same order page I have multiple products and each of them have the select menu with country names.

Now, each of those countries have different shipping prices, so what I want is when user pick any of those countries to show its shipping price under its input box.

Im not familiar with JQuery so can anyone write down the code that will make this work. From time to time I will be adding new countries inside drop down menu so it should be easy to add them inside JQuery too.

Thanks a lot!

Changes:
My Jquery code after suggestions:

```
$(function () {
    $('#country1').change(function () {
            var prices = {
            'United States':9.99,
            'United Kingdom':14,
            'India':11,
            'Germany':14
            };
        $('input[name=amount1]').val(prices);
    });
});
```

Comment: and we are supposed to guess where the prices are hidden in the provided html?

Comment: Your answer is to take a tutorial on Javascript and learn it, not ask someone to do all of your work for you.

Comment: guys, if you cant help there is no need for these kind of answers. Yes I know I need to learn JS, Im PHP developer and I am working on project that requires some of this JQ codes, so I asked for a quick help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this apart into smaller components, each of which is easily researchable and testable...

First you want to respond to the `select` element's `change` event.  Something like this:

```
$('#country1').change(function () {
    // respond to the event here
});
```

You also want to write a value to the `input` element.  Something like this:

```
$('input[name=amount1]').val(someValue);
```

Now, you also want to determine *what* that value is.  Given the information in the question, we can't do that for you.  So I'm going to assume you have or can create that logic.  The result then ends up being something like this:

```
$('#country1').change(function () {
    var someValue;
    // some logic to determine the value
    $('input[name=amount1]').val(someValue);
});
```

You'd do this for each pair of `select` and `input` elements.  Additionally, you also want to ensure that the elements exist before trying to bind to their `change` events (otherwise nothing will happen), so you can wrap the whole thing in the jQuery function so that it doesn't attempt to execute the code until the document's `ready` event:

```
$(function () {
    $('#country1').change(function () {
        var someValue;
        // some logic to determine the value
        $('input[name=amount1]').val(someValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks David for a nice explanations. Can you please check the updated thread above where I created the code based on your suggestions, but when I select a country name I get the [Object] and no values, any suggestions maybe?

Comment: @BorisZegarac: Because you created `prices` as an object.  The `input` can't translate it into just a string.  What value do you want to actually display in the `input`?  That's the value you'd set in the `val()` function.  In this case you might be able to select it from the object by referencing it as an array using the selected value in the `select`.  Something like: `$('input[name=amount1]').val(prices[$(this).val()]);`  (untested, but worth looking into)

Comment: Lovely! Working just as I needed. Thanks a lot David, rep. added.